# How to define a template class for a linked list node with pointer as template type

Tags: c++, c++11

How to define a node template for a linked list? I also want to keep the pointer type as template parameter so that I can change it to unique_ptr or shared_ptr depends on what available.

```
template<typename T, typename NodePtr>
struct node{
    T data;
    NodePtr parent = nullptr;
};
```

The question is that how to initiate this class so that Nodeptr will be `shared_ptr < Node <T ,what?> >` type?

Comment: Why not just `node<T>* parent;`?  That extra template parameter is not necessary (unless you have a good reason to be using it).

Comment: because I might want to use a different pointer type, say shared_ptr<T>

Comment: @user40129 You're definitely not going to share nodes between lists, so `std::shared_ptr` doesn't make sense. You're also most likely not going to have unique but transferrable ownership of nodes, so `std::unique_ptr` doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: Well... linked list is simplest, could be other graph type. Like a direct graph with no circles. but can have same parent..

Comment: @molbdnilo: What is the problem with using unique_ptr? `std::unique_ptr` is explicitly designed to allow transfer of ownership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Simplest" solution I can think of is a variadic template template parameter:

```
template<class T,template<class ...> class PTR_T>
struct Node {
    T data;
    PTR_T<Node> parent{nullptr};
};
```

This works with both `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` like this:

```
Node<int,std::shared_ptr> roots;
Node<int,std::unique_ptr> rootu;
```

As suggested by yourself, you'd have to introduce a type alias, if you want to use raw pointers:

```
template<class T> using raw_ptr = T*;
```

Comment: Add this line would. template<class T> using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, std::default_delete<T> > ;  template<class T> using raw_ptr = T*

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks for the catch I always forget that uniuque_ptr and shared ptr have different number of template parameters. Fixed it.

Comment: @user40129: That would be a possibility, but introduces the danger of name collisions with std::unique_ptr. My version now uses a variadic template template parameter (or is it the other way round).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to pass parameter `T`:

```
template <typename T>
struct node
{
  T data;
  node<T> * parent;
}
```